# vmlinuz does not point to the kernel in use

Tags: kernel, 22.04, initrd

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. It boots without any issue, however vmlinuz and initrd (including .old) point to the wrong configuration.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   261924 Jul  7 14:21 config-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   271879 May 30 09:18 config-6.0.0-1018-oem
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   273878 Jun 16 09:51 config-6.1.0-1015-oem
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Jul 25 13:27 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Jul 25 13:26 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 66632780 Jul 25 13:26 initrd.img-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 72256850 Jul  7 08:29 initrd.img-6.0.0-1018-oem
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 72992957 Jul 17 08:07 initrd.img-6.1.0-1015-oem
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Jul 25 13:26 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.0.0-1018-oem
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182800 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184476 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184980 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  6262331 Jul  7 14:21 System.map-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  6474638 May 30 09:18 System.map-6.0.0-1018-oem
-rw-------  1 root root  5299628 Jun 16 09:51 System.map-6.1.0-1015-oem
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Jul 25 13:26 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11586408 Jul  7 14:24 vmlinuz-5.15.0-78-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 12015784 May 30 09:32 vmlinuz-6.0.0-1018-oem
-rw-------  1 root root 12250568 Jun 16 09:49 vmlinuz-6.1.0-1015-oem
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       22 Jul 25 13:26 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.0.0-1018-oem

$ uname -r
6.1.0-1015-oem

$ dmesg | grep linux
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.1.0-1015-oem (buildd@bos03-amd64-046) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0,   
 GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun 16 09:51:49 UTC 2023
```

Is it just a simple case of removing the soft links and just pointing them to the correct locations or just wait until a kernel update and hope it will all get sorted out?

Also what is the point of the soft links as they don't seem to be used at boot, or is it a legacy thing?